# Oracle reports to excel spreadsheet avoid scientific notation

Tags: oracle, excel, spreadsheet, oraclereports

I have an oracle report that outputs to an spreadsheet. The spreadsheet automatically 
takes large numbers and converts them to scientific notation.

I've tried to avoid this by

1)Prepending a blank space like below in the query

```
select ' '||24534534534345353 "Really Long Number" from dual;
```

2)Prepending an apostrophe(') like below in the query

```
select ''''||24534534534345353 "Really Long Number" from dual;
```

The above two methods from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214233 didn't work. I still get
the scientific notation.

For 1, the space is simply ignored by excel

For 2, the quote is taken literally and printed along with the number.[Strangely, When I edit the cell by removing/adding a digit after the report is generated, the apostrophe(') goes away.]

I've also tried LPAD()/RPAD() with blank space. Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: How does the data make it into Excel? Using a `.csv` file? Or do you write an `.xls` or `.xlsx` directly somehow?

Comment: @Jonas Yes, the XLS file is generated directly by Oracle Reports.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question, so I suggest to put in your workaround as an answer and accept. It will help the next person who encounters the same issue.

Comment: @Gary Myers: Edit moved to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the following workaround with the non-breaking space character:

```
select 24534534534345353||chr(160) "Really Long Number" from dual;
```

It isn't very neat but this is the closest that I could get.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set the cell format to `0` in Excel? This will redisplay the full number:

[image]
(sorry for the ancient German Excel version...)

If you want to do it in VBA, [try something like](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/385790-how-do-i-set-excel-cell-format-text-vb-net)

```
Sub ShowFullNumber()
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
End Sub
```

which will do it for the currently selected cell(s).

Comment: Hi Jonas,thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the users want the report to be generated with the number format. They do not want to change the format, each time after the report is generated.

Comment: Well then you need to answer my other comment: how does the data actually make it into Excel?